# I can't solve this error, pls help me! Error: 'StorageUploadTask' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, dart

uploadToStorage() async
{
showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (c)
{
return LoadingAlertDialog();
}
);

```
String imageFileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(imageFileName);

StorageUploadTask storageUploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_imageFile);

StorageTaskSnapshot = await storageUploadTask.onComplete;

await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((urlImage){
  userImageUrl = urlImage;

  _registerUser();
});
```

}

Comment: Provide us more details, paste full error message and fix code snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of the `firebase_storage` package, the correct class is called `UploadTask` not `StorageUploadTask`.

See the API reference https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/UploadTask-class.html

Comment: Tkanks it's helped